# Visual Studio CodeやMSDNのようなWebドキュメントページはどのような技術で作れるのでしょうか?

Tags: document

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api)や[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system?view=net-7.0)のようなWebで閲覧可能なドキュメントを作りたいと考えています。
インターネット上で調べてみると、Pythonを使ったSphinx, GithubのPagesなどがあることがわかりましたが、その他にどのような作り方があるでしょうか?
見た目(デザイン)はVisual Studio Codeのような、
左にTable,右側にリンク,または検索バーなどがあるものがよいです。

当方、自身で作ったアプリケーションのドキュメントをMicrosoft Wordで作っていますが、ページ数が膨大なのとやはり使い勝手が良くないため移行したいと考えております。

教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ドキュメントコメントをきちんと書いているという前提であれば、以下のようなツールが存在しています。
いずれもドキュメントコメントをHTMLに変換してくれます。
試しに変換してみて、気に入ったものを採用してみてはいかがでしょうか。

- [Doxygen](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen)
- [Sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB)
- [DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/)

参考：[XML ドキュメント コメント](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/)